# Django i18n: Common causes for translations not appearing

Tags: python, django, translation, gettext, django-multilingual

I am making a multilingual Django website. I created a messages file, populated and compiled it. I checked the site (the admin in this case,) in my wanted language (Hebrew) and most phrases appear in Hebrew like they should, but some don't. I checked the source and these still appear as `_('Whatever')` like they should, also they are translated on the messages file, and yes, I remembered to do `compilemessages`.

What are some common causes for translations not to appear like that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Maybe the translated strings are marked as `fuzzy`?

Comment: You're cheating, Ofri :)

Yes, this is one of the reasons for missed translations, thank you.

Comment: This took me a while to figure out too. Any entries marked as "fuzzy" are not used. They are intended to be reviewed by a translator and until verified (by removing the fuzzy flag) are not displayed.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/gettext/Fuzzy-Entries.html#Fuzzy-Entries

Comment: After 11 years still a good answer. This is what bit me today.

Answer (score 24):

Just got hit by one.  I had the `locale/` directory in the root of my project, but by default [Django looks for translations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations) in the `INSTALLED_APPS` directories, and in the default translations.  So it didn't find the translations I added.  But some of my strings were in the default translations that come with Django (eg "Search") so a few strings were translated, which confused me.

To add the directory where my translations were to the list of places that Django will look for translations, I had to set the [LOCALE_PATHS setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOCALE_PATHS).  So in my case, where the `locale/` directory and `settings.py` were both in the root of the django project I could put the following in `settings.py`:

```
from os import path
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    path.join(path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__)), 'locale'),
)
```

Comment: Nowadays it looks like:
`LOCALE_PATHS = ((BASE_DIR / 'locale'), )`

Answer (score 17):

I'm trying to provide a complete check list:

- In `settings.py`, are `USE_I18N`, `USE_L10N`, `LANGUAGE_CODE`, and `LOCALE_PATHS` set properly?

  - See [this list](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html) for all allowed values of language identifiers. Note that Simplified Chinese is specified by `zh-hans`, not `zh-cn`.
- In `settings.py`, is `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` included in `MIDDLEWARE` [in correct order](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference)?
- Have you (re)run `django-admin makemessages -l <locale-name>` with the correct local name, [from the correct place](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#message-files)?

  - You can see an *incomplete* list of allowed locale name by running `ls your/path/to/python/site-packages/django/conf/locale/` on your machine, or by [taking a look at the source code](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/conf/locale)
  - **Note that you have to use `_` rather than `-` here.** For example, to specify simplified Chinese, execute `django-admin makemessages -l zh_Hans`, not `zh_CN` or `zh_hans` or `zh-Hans` or anything else.
- Have you removed all `fuzzy` tags in your PO file(s)?
- Have you (re)compiled the OP file(s) with `django-admin compilemessages`?
- Have you restarted the web server?

Additional notes:

- If some of your translation is overridden by Django's default translation, use [contextual markers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#contextual-markers) to bypass it. For example,

> models.py

```
first_name = models.CharField(
    pgettext_lazy('override default', 'first name'),
    max_length=30
)

last_name = models.CharField(
    pgettext_lazy('override default', 'last name'),
    max_length=150
)
```

> django.po

```
#: models.py:51
msgctxt "override default"
msgid "first name"
msgstr "姓"

#: models.py:55
msgctxt "override default"
msgid "last name"
msgstr "名"
```

and you'll see `姓`, `名` instead of the default `姓氏`, `名字`.

Comment: Very usefull list! I'd add a check that made me waste some hours: the presence of directory 'locale' in your app where the locales will be written. Very nice note on contextual markers that I didn't know of.

Answer (score 9):

A possible cause is [Lazy Translation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#lazy-translation).

In example, in views.py you should use **ugettext**:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```

But in models.py, you should use **ugettext_lazy**:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like it's not the problem in this case.

I log into the shell, and do `ugettext('My expression')`, and I get `'My expression'` instead of the translation. (Yes, I `activate`d the other language before doing this, and confirmed I can translate other strings with this function.)

Answer (score 9):

I was having this problem with my project right now. I had the variable LANGUAGES on settings.py set this way:

```
LANGUAGES = (
('en', _('English')),
('pt-br', _('Brazilian Portuguese')),
)
```

And a folder structure with a locale folder, and a subfolder pt-br inside. Turns out that my translations weren't loading. The LANGUAGES variable follows the pt-br pattern, and the folders must be on pt_BR pattern. At least that's the only way it's working here!

Comment: Same thing with pt-br here (using Django==1.10.5)

Comment: I had the same problem. the correct pattern for language code that contains '-'(hyphen) is '<code_prefix>_<CAPITAL_SUFFIX>' exmaple: `pt_BR`
so correct command is
`python manage.py makemessages -l=pt_BR`

Answer (score 8):

Hi just attach some fixes I had to do in the past:

- Restart the webserver!

In the setting file
- `USE_I18N = True` is needed

- django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware among middleware modules (but this is not your case for sure as long as Django will not care about your local at all)
- django.core.context_processors.i18n among TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

for sure I had other issues related to translations but I don't remember them all... hope this can help!

Comment: +1! In my case, I just had to restart the server. I'm using a nginx + gunicorn combination. Restarting gunicorn was enough. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another cause can be a wrong directory structure.

Read well the manage command's error message about which directory to create before running the `makemassages` command for the *app* translation. (It must be `locale` for an app, *not* `conf/locale`.) Note that the management commands work fine even with the wrong directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when I had `%` in my text, the translated text was not being used. There may be other characters that can cause this problem. I fixed the problem by escaping the `%` as `%%`.

Answer (score 0):

My answer here, all my translations were working except for 2 `DateField`s that I was using in a `ModelForm`.
Turns out that I had a widget in my `forms.py` that was not working well with the translations.

I just removed it for now so I can enjoy Xmas =D